# Access Is Denied When Making XMLHttpRequest Call In Excel Add-In Javascript

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to pull data from a web service into Excel by creating an add-in.  Pretty standard thing I thought.  But I am getting Access is Denied on my call to...

```
        // make request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var factTable = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:51805/Api/FactData?aaaViewName=aaa_telecom_services_forecast", false);
```

Specifically on the open line.

Why on earth would it block access?  What can I do to get my data?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this outside the context of an add-in?  E.g., in JSFiddle?

Comment: No, but the web request works fine in a browser.  I just tried JSFiddle, but nothing happened when I clicked run.  Do I need to create some kind of HTML?  This is my first time in JS now it seems to be being forced on me to create add-ins.

Comment: What HTTP code are you getting? Easiest way to test would be to open the add-in via. Excel online (browser). You can go to Insert > add-in > Manage add-in > Upload add-in file. Then you can open developer tool and look under network tab to see why it is failing. One reason could be that it is using HTTP instead of HTTPS (just my speculation..). We do have samples of add-in connecting to external service such as here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-ASPNET-QuickBooks. I couldn't locate any sample that used localhost request over http.

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to be due to the fact that the office add-in was using https and the web service was using http.  Even enabling CORS didn't help.  I fixed by right clicking on the web service project and in the properties window (not project properties) setting 'SSL Enabled' to true and using the https version of the URL instead in the web service call.